# LiDAR Basics - How classes are determined at LiDAR data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar

LiDAR data have classes as Medium vegetation, Buildings, Ground, Model Key and more. What determines these classes ? is it combination of intensity and scan angle rank ? how to reclassify these classes using ArcGIS ?